# How does dataannotationsvalidator generate ErrorMessage for RequiredAttribute in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net, blazor-server-side

Because there is a localized demand for this kind of error prompt, I initially thought that this could be used

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(opt =>
{
     opt.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new ModelValidatorProvider());
}
```

To deal with its error message, but found that it is useless, is it possible to use a similar method to deal with it?

Comment: `ModelMetadataDetailsProviders` is MVC, are you writing server side code with controllers or Blazor Components?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis,Server Inside